# Why do I get a ValueError when using skimage.filters.threshold_local in python?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have encountered an error when using the function `skimage.filters.threshold_local` in python:

```
threshold = skimage.filters.threshold_local(data, 7, method='gaussian', offset=0, mode='nearest')

  File "/mnt/depot64/NPsoftware/simnibs/charm_dev/charm_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/skimage/filters/thresholding.py", line 209, in threshold_local
    check_nD(image, 2)

  File "/mnt/depot64/NPsoftware/simnibs/charm_dev/charm_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/skimage/_shared/utils.py", line 320, in check_nD
    raise ValueError(msg_incorrect_dim % (arg_name, '-or-'.join([str(n) for n in ndim])))

ValueError: The parameter `image` must be a 2-dimensional array
```

For my understanding, the `image` can be N-dimensional, but why does it give me the error? Do I misunderstand something? In my case, the `data` is a 3D image with `dtype` of `float32`, and the element values range from `-2000` to `+2000`.

Comment: The message clearly says that the function wants a 2D image, and the code is doing an explicit check for that. Not much else to say.

Comment: @BoarGules In the docmentation, it is said image(N, M[, …, P]) ndarray, so it should be able to accept ND images (N>2). https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.filters.html

Comment: I am aware. But the code is what you have to work with

Answer (score 1):

`threshold_local` only accepts grayscale image. So try to convert your `data` into grayscale first

```
from skimage.color import rgb2gray
from skimage import filters

data = ...
grayscale = rgb2gray(data)
threshold = filters.threshold_local(grayscale, 7, method='gaussian', offset=0, mode='nearest')
```

Comment: My `data` is not an RGB image. It is a 3D image. So `data.shape` is (128, 128, 100), and the range of elements is [-2000, 2000].